# Model with instance won't save to DB but no error message in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm having an issue saving a Form with an instance. I have a model with a Foreign Key but I want to save it - but nothing is appearing in table and there doesn't appear to be any error message.

The model is:

```
class AboutMe(models.Model):
    MyGender                   = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = GENDER_CHOICES)


class Message(models.Model):
    MySubject     =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    MyMessage     =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    MyFromID      =  models.ForeignKey(AboutMe)

class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        exclude = ('MyRead', 'MyDeleted', 'MySpam', 'MyDate', 'MyTime', 'MyFromID', 'MyToID')
    MyMessage = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

def Contact(request):
        myid = request.session["AboutMe_id"]

        Sender = AboutMe.objects.get(pk=myid)
        if request.method == "POST":
            message = ContactForm(request.POST, instance=Sender)
            if message.is_valid():
                message.save(commit=False)
                #return HttpResponse(myid)
                message.MyRead = False
                message.MyDeleted = False
                message.MySpam = False
                message.MyDate = datetime.date.today()
                message.MyTime = timezone.now()
                message.MyToID = int(1)
                message.save()
                message.save_m2m()
                return redirect('/')
        else:
            message = ContactForm(request.POST, instance=Sender)
        return render(request, "contact.html", {'form': message,})
```

I've tried this too:

```
def Contact(request):
    myid = request.session["AboutMe_id"]

    Sender = AboutMe.objects.get(pk=myid)
    if request.method == "POST":
        messageForm = ContactForm(request.POST, instance=Sender)    
        if messageForm.is_valid():
            message = messageForm.save(commit=False)
            #message.save(commit=False)
            #return HttpResponse(myid)
            message.MyRead = False
            message.MyDeleted = False
            message.MySpam = False
            message.MyDate = datetime.date.today()
            message.MyTime = timezone.now()
            message.MyToID = int(1)
            message.save()
            #message.save_m2m()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        messageForm = ContactForm( instance=Sender)
    return render(request, "contact.html", {'form': messageForm,})
```

Comment: Maybe my django knowledge is outdated, but it doesn't look right that you are using `instance=Sender` in the POST if block.  Also, does the indenting on your question match what you really have? (The first line with `messageForm =` looks to be indented too far)

Comment: I get returned to /. No error messages and nothing in the DB. So that block is executing on posting. But not saving.

Comment: @user673600 The `MyFromID` is a foreign key, but you do not allow nulls. That would explain why saving is not happening (it should throw an error though). Add `models.ForeignKey(AboutMe, null=True, blank=True)` and recreate that table one more time (drop it and `syncdb` it).

Comment: I've added this line MyFromID      =  models.ForeignKey(AboutMe, null=True, blank=True) and rebuilt. But still having the same issue.

Comment: @user673600 That's weird, indeed. Are you sure it is passing `messageForm.is_valid()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the wrong instance to the form, because the form is for the `Message` model, not your `AboutMe` model.

Here is the corrected version, along with some additional checks:

1. You should always make sure you have a valid session. If you have `request.session["AboutMe_id"]` and the session has expired, you'll get a `KeyError` (as the key will not be in the session). Using the `get` method of dictionaries will suppress this error. Instead, if the key doesn't exists, the method will return `None`. If the session has expired, we should not move forward - so we redirect to the root.
2. Even if the session is valid - it may not contain a valid value for your model. In that case, this `AboutMe.objects.get(pk=myid)` will raise an exception. To prevent that, we wrap it in a try/except block. If the object doesn't exists, it means the value from the session is invalid. We delete the key and then redirect the user to the root.
3. Finally, you should always have a condition if the form is invalid; so I added that check as well.

The rest of the changes are mainly formatting. Method names should start with lowercase letters, as should normal names. Only class names should be in InitialCaps.

```
def contact(request):
    myid = request.session.get("AboutMe_id")
    if not myid:
        # session has expired
        return redirect('/')
    try:
        sender = AboutMe.objects.get(pk=myid)
    except AbouMe.DoesNotExist:
        # Invalid id in session
        del request.session['AboutMe_id']
        return redirect('/')

    messageForm = ContactForm(request.POST or {})
    if request.method == "POST":      
        if messageForm.is_valid():
            message = messageForm.save(commit=False)
            message.MyRead = False
            message.MyDeleted = False
            message.MySpam = False
            message.MyDate = datetime.date.today()
            message.MyTime = timezone.now()
            message.MyToID = 1
            message.MyFromID = sender
            message.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            # form is not valid
            return render(request, "contact.html", {'form': messageForm})
     else:
         # return empty form
         return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': messageForm})
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at that and use that. I was under the impression that by using instances, I'd never need to explicitly declare message.MyFromId = sender

Comment: The ContactForm rendered fine before as expected. What do you mean by 'wrong instance to the form'? Thanks again.

Comment: The form is for the `ModelForm` model, but you were passing it an instance of your `AboutMe` model.

Comment: I thought that was how one dealt with the FK arrangement. I was originally trying formset i.e. formset = BookInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=author) So should instance always refer to the same object.

Comment: Yes. The way you deal with FK is by grabbing an instance of the object (you do that with `commit=False`), and then assigning the key manually. You also didn't need the `save_m2m()` since you don't have any `ManyToMany` relationships; and `int(1)` is the same as `1` since `1` is an integer (`'1'` is a string and then you'd need `int('1')` to convert it into an integer).

Comment: Thanks. The issue is now that the FK is not taking the value from sender and ending up NULL in the database. You can tell from my code I've been trying lots of variations to get this working so apologies for the rough state of it!

Comment: Try the updated version. There was a typo in your model fields.

Comment: Silly me, its late, I didn't spot that. Thanks! One more thing. When the form is loading for the first time, I get the errors "This field is required.". What's causing this?

Comment: It should not say that. Open a new browser window and try it again.

Comment: I've tried this and opened a new window, but I still get the missing fields on loading the form initially.

Comment: Ah, sorry - change `messageForm = ContactForm(request.POST or {})` to `messageForm = ContactForm(request.POST or None)`